# How did Lisbeth Salander empty the bank accounts?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-girl-with-the-dragon-tattoo

At the end of [*The Girl With the Dragon Tattoo*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1568346/) Lisbeth Salander transfers of lot of a money..

How did she do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shown that Lisbeth is an **expert hacker**.

It's stated that she has accessed Wennerstrom's computer because she gives the information to Blomquist to prove what he said was true.

Blomquist says..

> "I have access to his computers, and his accountants and his lawyers."

Clearly with this information she is able to move Wennerstrom's money around, transfer it where she wants it and give instructions on how to withdraw it.

They are numbered accounts and if you know the numbers and apparently have the correct passwords you can do pretty much anything...at least in a movie.

She goes to the bank office and says to the official

> **Salander**: I have accounts at Bank of Kroenenfeld, Cayman Islands. >I'd like to transfer them and convert to bonds.
>
> [As she writes an account number on a slip of paper from
>   memory, Herr Wagner notices - as she intends - the pen
>   she’s using - from the venerable Zimmerstal Hotel.]
>
> **Banker/Wagner** : Naturally, you have the clearing codes.
>
> **Salander**: Naturally.